# Rails form_for helper authenticated parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, remote-forms

I have some legacy rails code that specifies authenticated: true for a remote form.  But as far as I can tell the parameter does nothing. Perhaps the developer wanted to include an authenticity token?

I did a search but found no documentation concerning this parameter.

```
<%= form_for @house, url: action_path, method: "PATCH", authenticated: true, remote: true, html: { id: 'house-edit-contact' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :website, 'website: ' %>
    <%= f.text_field :website %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :phone, 'phone: ' %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
    <br><br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit Changes" %>
  <% end %>
```

For what it's worth here is the resultant HTML, but I see nothing related to authentication in it:

```
<form class="edit_house" id="house-edit-contact" action="/houses/7112?field=contact-info&amp;placement=contact_info" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
  <br>
  <label for="house_website">website: </label>
  <input type="text" value="portofhopecenters.org" name="house[website]" id="house_website">
  <br>
  <label for="house_phone">phone: </label>
  <input type="text" value="208-463-0118" name="house[phone]" id="house_phone">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Changes" data-disable-with="Submit Changes">
</form>
```

Comment: are you using devise?

Comment: @Bhupati Yes, but what does that parameter do for devise?  I see nothing in the generated HTML for devise to use. If I take out `authenticated: true`, the before_action filter for authenticating the user still works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<%= form_for @house, url:(action_path, authenticated: true), method: "PATCH", remote: true, html: { id: 'house-edit-contact' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :website, 'website: ' %>
    <%= f.text_field :website %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :phone, 'phone: ' %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
    <br><br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit Changes" %>
  <% end %>
```

but as you are using `devise` you need not pass it from the `view`
you can simply control from the `before_action: authenticate_user!, only: [:update]` in the `controller` itself.